# Не корректно работают кастомные иконки Яндекс.Карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Пытаюсь разработать генерацию карты с заранее определёнными по координатам точками. 
Сначала информация о точках на карте собирается в массив в PHP:

```
$mapData['features'][]=array(
    "type"=>"Feature",
    "id"=>$numb,
    "geometry"=>array(
        "type"=>"Point",
        "coordinates"=> Array(55,55),//взял координаты для примера
    ),
    "options"=>Array(
      "iconLayout" => 'default#image',
      "iconImageHref" => '/images/icon.png',
      "iconImageSize" => Array(24, 30),
      "iconImageOffset" => Array(10,10),
    ),
    "properties"=>array(
        "balloonContentBody" => $contentBody,
        "balloonContentFooter"=>"",
        "iconCaption"=> $item['NAME'],
        'iconContent' => '',
        "iconCaptionMaxWidth"=> '300',
        "hintContent"=>"<strong>".$item['NAME']."</strong>"
    ),

);
```

Далее, когда массив собран, преобразуем его в javascript-массив и вставляем в скрипт карты:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ymaps.ready(init);

});
function init () {
    var dataR=<?=CUtil::PhpToJSObject($JsonData)?>;
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.50, 37.64],
        zoom: 10,
        controls:['zoomControl']
    }, {
        searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
    }),
    objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
        clusterize: false,
        gridSize: 32,
        clusterDisableClickZoom: true
    });
    myMap.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);
    objectManager.add(dataR);
    myMap.setBounds(objectManager.getBounds(), {
        checkZoomRange: true
    });   
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я указываю создание кастомной иконки для метки (элемент массива "options" в первом курсе php-кода), то она генерируется, но по нажатию на неё ничего не происходит - то есть контент "балуна" не открывается. Как только из основного массива мы убираем "options" - всё начинает работать корректно со стандартными метками.

В чем проблема, может кто-нибудь подсказать?)

Answer (score 1):

Проблему удалось решить. В элемент массива options нужно было добавить массив iconShape. 
У меня получилось так:

```
$mapData['features'][]=array(
    "type"=>"Feature",
    "id"=>$numb,
    "geometry"=>array(
        "type"=>"Point",
        "coordinates"=> Array(55,55),//взял координаты для примера
    ),
    "options"=>Array(
        "iconLayout" => 'default#image',
        "iconImageHref" => '/images/icon.png',
        "iconImageSize" => Array(24, 30),
        "iconImageOffset" => Array(10,10),
        "iconShape" => Array(
            "type" => 'Circle',
            "coordinates" => array(0, 0),
            "radius" => 25
        ),
    ),
    "properties"=>array(
        "balloonContentBody" => $contentBody,
        "balloonContentFooter"=>"",
        "iconCaption"=> $item['NAME'],
        'iconContent' => '',
        "iconCaptionMaxWidth"=> '300',
        "hintContent"=>"<strong>".$item['NAME']."</strong>"
    ),
);
```

Подробнее: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Placemark-docpage/#Placemark__param-options.iconShape